# How to deal with sync (blocking) call making the UI unresponsive

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, system.reactive

Given this piece of code, I noticed that my UI blocked for a while (Windows even popped a message saying that the application wasn't responding.

```
using (var zip = await downloader.DownloadAsZipArchive(downloadUrl))
{
    var temp = FileUtils.GetTempDirectoryName();
    zip.ExtractToDirectory(temp);   // BLOCKING CALL

    if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
    {
        Directory.Delete(folderPath, true);
    }

    var firstChild = Path.Combine(temp, folderName);
    Directory.Move(firstChild, folderPath);
    Directory.Delete(temp);
}
```

After some checks, I discovered that the line that says:

```
zip.ExtractToDirectory(temp);
```

is the culprit.

I have thought that turning it into will be enough to make it work:

```
await Task.Run(() => zip.ExtractToDirectory(temp));
```

But… is that a good solution to this problem?

I have a background with `System.Reactive` (I'm all in with Reactive Programming) and I would like to know if there's a more elegant way to deal with this.

Comment: If a sync call is blocking, then make it async. That's pretty much the only answer there is.

Comment: the ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory isn't async and I cannot make it async because it's not mine, but part of the .NET Framework :(

Comment: Not "async" as in putting `async` in front of it. Async as in "asynchronous", as in getting it off the UI thread. Whether that means putting it in a `Task`, `Thread`, `BackgroundWorker`, or whatever is an implementation detail that doesn't often have a single correct answer.

Comment: If you're all in with Rx, you wouldn't have TPL and async all over the place. Combining the two is generally more pain than it's worth.

Comment: @SuperJMN - What's the problem with using Rx to do this?

Comment: @enigmativity I don't know, but I always try to turn code into Rx before doing anything else, but I don't know it this scenario makes sense for it.

Comment: @SuperJMN - It seems like RX would be perfectly fine here to me.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm glad it is, but I don't know how to use it with this piece of code. This is part of an async Task Execute() method that I'm using for my "script interpreter". I used Tasks because it seemed more natural in my scenario. This is the original file I have right now, should you want to take a look. How to make it RX? https://github.com/WoA-project/WOA-Deployer/blob/master/Source/Deployer/Tasks/GitHubUnpack.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little bit nasty doing this in Rx. Combining a `Task<IDisposable>` is rough. THis is what I got:

```
Observable
    .FromAsync(() => downloader.DownloadAsZipArchive(downloadUrl))
    .SelectMany(z =>
        Observable
            .Using(() => z, zip => Observable.Start(() =>
            {
                var temp = FileUtils.GetTempDirectoryName();
                zip.ExtractToDirectory(temp);   // BLOCKING CALL

                if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
                {
                    Directory.Delete(folderPath, true);
                }

                var firstChild = Path.Combine(temp, folderName);
                Directory.Move(firstChild, folderPath);
                Directory.Delete(temp);             
            })))
    .Subscribe();
```

Comment: Crazy, but lovely. I definitely have to try (and understand) this. Thank you master!

Comment: I wonder how it would result with this slighly different DeploymentTask I have, that doesn't doesn't use the async DownloadZipArchive as starting point: https://github.com/WoA-project/WOA-Deployer/blob/master/Source/Deployer/Tasks/AzureDevOpsUnpack.cs#L61

Comment: Upvote, for yet another nicely handled RX answer. I must admit i have never used `.Using`

Comment: @MichaelRandall - `Observable.Using` is essential when using any `IDisposable` resource - when the observable ends the resource is disposed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as you can imagine `ExtractToDirectory` will take time, unfortunately there is no `async` version of this method as it's a CPU bound workload.

What you can do (controversially), is offload it to the threadpool, you will incur a threadpool thread penalty though, meaning you a taking a threadpool thread and blocking it (using up a valuable resources). However because the `Task` is awaited, it will free up the UI context.

```
await Task.Run(() => zip.ExtractToDirectory(temp));
```

Note, although this will solve the problem, the best approach here would be to use an `TaskCompletionSource`. This is basically is events for Tasks (for lack of better words), it will save tying up a thread needlessly.

**Update** Great comment by [olitee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4311736/olitee)

> Slightly less controversially... you could extend this to use:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => zip.ExtractToDirectory(temp), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

> which will force the creation of a
> new dedicated thread for the operation. Although there will be an
> extra penalty for creating that thread, rather than recycling a
> pooled one - but this is less of an issue for a long running operation like this.

Comment: Slightly less controversially ;) ... you could extend this to use: `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => zip.ExtractToDirectory(temp), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);` - which will force the creation of a new dedicated thread for the operation. Although there will be an extra penalty for creating that thread, rather the recycling a pooled one - but this is less of an issue for a long running operation like this.

Comment: @olitee thanks for that, i have added it to the answer, and attributed

Answer (score 0):

I would most likely refactor the zip extraction and directory creation code into it's own method. This will make it easier later on to offload to a thread. It will also have the added benefit of making the caller decide if it wants to run it on another thread or not.

```
public void ExtractZip(ZipFile zip)
{
   var temp = FileUtils.GetTempDirectoryName();
   zip.ExtractToDirectory(temp);   // BLOCKING CALL

   if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
   {
       Directory.Delete(folderPath, true);
   }

   var firstChild = Path.Combine(temp, folderName);
   Directory.Move(firstChild, folderPath);
   Directory.Delete(temp);
}
```

Then have the top level method download the file and extract zip

```
// this method contains async IO code aswell as CPU bound code
// that has been offloaded to another thread
public async Task ProcessAsync()
{
   using (var zip = await downloader.DownloadAsZipArchive(downloadUrl))
   {
      // I would use Task.Run until it proves to be a performance bottleneck
      await Task.Run(() => ExtractZip(zip));
   }
}
```